# MonoDevelop output from a C# code (on a Mac)

Tags: c#, macos, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop on a Mac. I wrote a program, I made sure it is correct MonoDevelop has all necessary to build an exe file from it. MonoDevelop says "Build Successful." However, no output appears. When I select "Run", I'm told:

```
Cannot open assembly '/Users/.../Projects/.../.../bin/Debug/XY.exe': No such file or directory.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGINT
```

And, indeed, no exe file has been created. Do you know how to create the exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like many things don't work without Xamarin. This was one of them. Installing Xamarin solved the problem.